# json4s extract with default values

Tags: scala, json4s

Here is my test cases

```
case class WithDefaultValueHolder(values: Seq[WithDefaultValue])
case class WithDefaultValue(name: String, gender: String = "male")

it("default with valid json"){
  val res = WithDefaultValueHolder(Seq(WithDefaultValue("Bob")))
  parse("""{"values":[{"name":"Bob","gender":"male"}]}""").extract[WithDefaultValueHolder](
    DefaultFormats, Manifest.classType(classOf[WithDefaultValueHolder])) shouldBe (res)
}
```

Below test also passed.It considers malformed json as valid json for default values. Why? How to restrict this behaviour. How to fail below test case?

```
it("default with invalid json"){
  val res = WithDefaultValueHolder(Seq(WithDefaultValue("Bob")))
  parse("""{"values":[{"name":"Bob","xyz":"abc"}]}""").extract[WithDefaultValueHolder](
    DefaultFormats, Manifest.classType(classOf[WithDefaultValueHolder])) shouldBe (res)
}
```